# Stuck at installation

Tags: system-installation

As you can see my Ubuntu installation is stuck at different parts with the cursor spinning. I tried some fixes, but no hope. Last chance I installed Ubuntu on my wife's laptop with my SSD, and it's working fine, but mine stuck. I tried to plug back my SSD into my laptop, but still the cursor keeps spinning and it's not responding.

HP Pavilion Notebook Y7X89EA#ABV
Intel Core i7 7500u 2.70 GHz
8GB RAM
SSD Hik Vision 120 GB

Legacy mode is enabled and I boot from the USB that has UEFI. Also I checked and my Ubuntu version is 100% working.

[image]

Distributions Used:

Linux Mint 21.2
Ubuntu 20.04
Ubuntu 22.04

I checked the integrity for all ISOs and they are all good.

Comment: Distributions Used Lunix Mint 21.2 Ubuntu 20.04 Ubuntu 22.04

I checked the integrity for all iso and they are all good

Comment: Also @guiverc i used rufus Default MBR partiton Scheme 
Bios or UEFI 
FAT32

Comment: You are using *reformat* options, as a *clone* method of write of ISO does not allow you to select partition scheme. Your reformat will make it work on some hardware & not on others by design (ie. your chosen write method needs to suit the hardware you'll use it for), plus you need to use a version of `rufus` capable of writing that release (*given you're reformatting the ISO; with 22.04 differing to 20.04 in this case*). Linux Mint is **not** a Ubuntu system (just Ubuntu based) so is off-topic here. You mention two releases, but not which 20.04 or 22.04 product, ISO or installer selected.

Comment: Used 20.04 and 22.04 both the same problem

Comment: Im Still new I will try to use DD Mode and Tell you

Comment: Being specific helps, eg. If the ISO is `ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` what is useful is not just Ubuntu 22.04, but Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop.  The .3 gives specific details as to kernel stack on the ISO (5.15 if Server, & 6.2 if Desktop), plus the Desktop/Server which differ. Ubuntu 22.04 isn't that specific (*given different ISOs have different options for the same release; you deciding which you'll use at download time*)

Comment: ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64
ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64

Answer (score 0):

some laptops has a "linux-blocking" bios feature, I suggest you to do a research and, in case you have one of those laptops, to update and set correctly your bios. For example my Lenovo ideapad blocks every operative system wich is not windows.

Comment: It Worked Fine on Lenovo Ideapad i didnt Have Problem